# How to access a string as a variable,which is already declared

Tags: python-3.x

I declared a variable,a as an integer and another variable,b(equals to 'a') as a string. I cannot access variable,a from b

```
a=10
b='a'
print(b)
```

I expected the output of 10, but the actual output is 'a'

Answer (score 0):

When you set `b='a'`, you're actually setting `b` equal to the literal character `'a'`. Python won't let you access the value of variable `a` from the character `'a'` because the language is designed to allow you to have a variable name in one place and then be able to print out that variable name somewhere else without accidentally accessing that variable's value.

To the best of my knowledge, there isn't a way in Python to store a value as a character literal and then treat it as a variable name somewhere else. This makes sense because if later in the program you wanted to print out something like `'an error was detected'`, you wouldn't want it to say `'10n error w10s detected'`

You should change the second line to `b=a` if you want to access the value of the variable `a` from variable `b`.

Comment: I updated my answer to hopefully provide a little more context. If I understand correctly, you want to be able to store the value of the character `'a'` and then use that same value to access the number assigned to variable `a`. Unfortunately, for the reason I explained in my answer these are two incompatible behaviors and you won't be able to do both at once.

Comment: hmm,i think eval function makes a sense to my question,thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

In python, literals enclosed within single quotes `'` or double quotes `"` are treated as strings. So, your solution should have set `b=a` as this tells the Python interpreter set the value of `b` to be equal to `a` at that point in time.

If my answer answered your question, consider adding it as an answer.

Comment: setting b=a,i know that.but, i want to access a from string 'a'.how?

Comment: Are you looking for eval(b)? Terrible idea, though! change your print to print(eval(b))

Comment: yeah,that i don't know that .Thanks!